# Responsive Downloads

Tags: javascript, web-applications, download, connection, responsive-design

I'm looking for a way to serve images based on devise type and connection speed.

There has been a lot of talk about  a new 'picture' element being tied into the new HTML5 spec. As far as I know, this will work more like media queries and download source images purely based on the size of the devise.

I think what I want can be achieved by speed testing required downloads and using that data to decide which image sets should be retrieved from the server.

The problems with this method (and this might not be the best way) is that network speeds can vary, and so the results from a one shot test could be misleading.

Also, to get continuous updates on state of the current download speeds you would need to continually run these tests. You could tie the tests into ajax requests so that you don't need to download more data than is required of app anyway, but this would be less than ideal for continual monitoring of  network strength. You would only get updates when the user sends a request to the server.

What would be grand is if there was an device driven API that could tell us connection type and signal strength before we send anything back from a server. Does that exist? Is this the best idea? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

It does not exist, but would be amazing if it did.

Images for mobile devices are still very up-in-the-air and we're still waiting on the best solution that will solve the problem for small mobile devices on slow cellular networks, as well as large-screen retina displays on super-fast networks. srcsets, the `picture` element, SVGs, etc., are all used as a stop-gap, but they all have their fallbacks and downsides.

Check out this article from Smashing, it goes into great depth on the problem and potential solutions as we wait for the "right" one.

http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/29/the-state-of-responsive-web-design/

Comment: talking about smashing magazine, there is a fresh article http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/02/clown-car-technique-solving-for-adaptive-images-in-responsive-web-design/